# Doubt in proof of Bertrand Postulate

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

I studied proof of Bertrand Postulate from M Ram Murthy Problems in analytic number theory and completely understood it .

In M Ram Murthy Book , Statement of Bertrand Postulate is (1) - For n sufficiently large , there exists a prime between n and 2n.

But while I was looking at Book Introduction to sieve methods and applications by Ram Murthy the statement of Bertrand Postulate is (2) - For every n $\geq$ 1 , there always exists a prime between n and 2n .

> Can someone please tell how To deduce 2nd statement from statement 1 ie to prove that for each n $ \geq $  1 , there exists a prime between n and 2n .

Comment: You cannot deduce (2) from (1) unless you know what the sufficiently large $n$ that is referenced in (1) and then deal with the remaining finite number of cases.

Comment: @Ciarán Ó Raghaillaigh Can you please tell how you are sure that (2) can't be deduced from (1) ?

Comment: The 2nd statement is clearly not true! It fails for $n=1$. A slightly weaker form of the Bertrand's postulate states the result is true for all $n>1$.

Comment: I did not say it cannot be deduced, I just gave a caveat for what such a deduction would look like. My comment is about statements of the form "for sufficiently large $n$, P(n) is true".

Comment: @SL_MathGuy It depends what you mean by "between". There's certainly a prime weakly between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statement 1 probably tells you something like "if $n \geq 750$, then there is a prime between $n$ and $2n$". That's the bound that I was taught, where my proof ultimately hit the inequality $\frac{n \log 4}{3} < (2 + \sqrt{2n}) \log(2n)$ that was required to fail.

Now you can obtain statement 2 by checking that there is a prime between $2$ and $4$, between $3$ and $6$, …, between $749$ and $1498$.